# OpenCV Video modules not working on Ubuntu Pycharm

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, ubuntu-16.04

I've been trying to run video modules for OpenCV on my machine running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I've installed Pycharm. There is no error whatsoever but no video is being displayed.However, it is working perfectly fine with image modules.

```
     import cv2

     cap = cv2.VideoCapture('project_video.mp4')
     while (cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
          if ret == True:
             cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
              if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                 break
          else:
              break


    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: correct your indentation, in python it is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. This happened because both the versions of Python i.e. 2.7 and 3.5 were installed. So one of them has to be uninstalled for the program to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Make sure your indentation is correct like below.
> 2. Try to import opencv module in the python shell.

```
   cap = cv2.VideoCapture('project_video.mp4')
   while (cap.isOpened()):
      ret, frame = cap.read()
      if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)

      # Press Q on keyboard to  exit
      if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

      else:
         break


   cap.release()
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Done That. Still Not Working.;(

Answer (score 0):

May be your code format has problem.
This is after formatted.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('project_video.mp4')
while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```